# How to persist a JPA autogenerated value before commit?

Tags: java, jpa

Hi I am beginner on the JPA world, I have a question on the auto-generated id. We are using OpenJPA, My application requires that one operation which creates bunch of related objects must be inside a single transaction which will be part of global transaction (XA). I am struggling in get the auto-generated id and use it to set values in other object. Here is the snapshot:

```
@ENTITY
@Table(name="TDepart")

class Department{

  private long id;

  @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.TABLE)

  public long getId();

}

//And some classes like

class Professor {
  void setDepartmentId(long id);
}

Now I have a business operation:

void doSomething()
{

  Department depart = new Department();

  handleProfessors (depart);
  handleStudent (depart);
  //and someother rountines need to refer department
}

//sample code which will getId
void handleProfessors(Department depart)
{

  Professor p = new Professor (); 

  p.setDepartmentId(depart.getId);

}
```

So the Department.getId() will be called several times. The doSomething() will be in a single managed transaction, but the GeneratedValue will use an unmanaged tx. Now may problem is: whenever the getId is called, it will return a new value, and when the department is final persisted, the id is the latest number, so all other objects refer to an non-exists department. Is there anyway to handle this so that the id is (kindof) persist?

I have a loose requirement solution, which will create an dummy department first and persist it, so the ID is not change. The code is similar to this:

```
void doSomething() 
{
  Department depart = createEmptyDepartment(); // always new tx so department is created;

  try { 
    reallyDoSomehing(); // tx required so it is part of global tx
  }
  catch (SomeException e) {
    removeEmptyDepartment(depart);
  }
```

Now I do not know how I can set the tx for `removeEmptyDepartment()`, if is required it will use the global request so it will be rollback as well. If it is new tx it will cause a deadlock since `reallyDoSomething()` will lock the db row.

Please, give me some ideas on how to solve it.

Thanks,
Howard.

Comment: Do you have @Id annotation?

Answer (score 3):

I don't fully understand your issue, but I'm thinking that rather than setting the departmentId in your professor class, you should be setting the Department instead
i.e.

```
 void setDepartmentId(long id);
```

change to

```
 void setDepartment(Department d);
```

The id components should be handled automatically by the entity manager

Comment: Thanks. This will help a lot. However not all routines are just entity reference. For example, there is a JMS message sending (which uses same XA tx) which also calls this getId().